# Get parent document values from sub-document in java

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql, document, subdocument

Let's say I have this Document

```
{
  uuid: 29f26148-4d55-4b4b-8e07-900fda686a67
  ...
  ...
  ban: {
         issued_time: *time_issued*
         expire_time: *time_expire*
       }
}
```

In my code I queried to get all the sub documents which didn't expire yet.

```
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("ban.expire_time", BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$gt", System.currentTimeMillis()).get());
        MongoCursor<Document> iterator = OnimaMongo.getPlayers().find(query).iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Document document = iterator.next();
        }
```

How can I get the uuid from the parent document ?

Comment: Did you see what fields and values are there in the `document`?

Comment: No I didn’t check

Comment: You can try the `get` method to get the `uuid` value from the `document`: [Document#get()](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/javadoc/org/bson/Document.html#get-java.lang.Object-).